# Get the parent taxonomy for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

I have a custom post type called 'listing' and a custom taxonomy called 'listing-category'

I am trying to create a class for the single-listing.php posts that is the slug of the parent custom taxonomy only eg:

STAY
- Hotel
- B&B

EAT
- Cafes
- Bakery

SHOP
- Food
- Shoes

So for single posts under hotel - I need to create a class of 'stay' as all posts under that class will have the same style.

What I hope to output is for example:

```
<div id="main-content" class="stay">
```

This previous question seems closest but I can't seem to get it working for my project: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term

I've been going around in circles for about two days with this so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that answer you have given the link to is OK and solves your problem as well. May be you do wrong implementation.

Here is sample code for your case:

```
global $post;
$ctp_listing_cats=wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'listing-category' );

if (!empty($ctp_listing_cats[0]->term_id)){
   $topparent=get_term_top_most_parent($ctp_listing_cats[0]->term_id,'listing-category');
}

//...
echo '<div id="main-content" class="'.$topparent->name.'">';
```

`get_term_top_most_parent()` function of the given code is the function from another answer you gave link to.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing - I tried so many ways to get that previous example to work but with your sample code is it working perfectly - thank you so much :-)!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to add one more parameter to **wp_get_post_terms**,

When you set **'parent' => 0** and it return only parents.

**For example:**
$company_locations    = wp_get_post_terms( $car_id, 'location', array('parent' => 0) );